# include laravel view inside script

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have created two sidebars for my Laravel application. One is for desktop view and another is for mobile view. I want to include the mobile view sidebar when the screen width is less than 576px otherwise desktop view sidebar should be loaded.

**Here is my code**

```
<script>
        if (screen.width < 576)
        {
            $('#wrapper').append('@include('layouts.mobile-sidebar')');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#wrapper').append('@include('layouts.sidebar')');
        }
    </script>
```

The above code doesn't work, the reason is being that all the HTML inside the sidebar view is not inside the single quotes of append function.

Can anyone suggest how can I include the view based on script condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
...

$('#wrapper').append({!! @include('layouts.mobile-sidebar') !!});
```